# how to order multi text box

Tags: c#, string, methods, controls, stringbuilder

I'm trying to order 5 text box in `StringBuilder` But the result always comes out random.. In short, what I want to do is arrange for a 5 text box to generate the same written text to compare it with a my database..
this text in my database

```
11111 22222 33333 44444 55555
```

Each time I run my app, the order varies like this.

```
55555 44444 11111 33333 22222
```

or

```
22222 11111 55555 44444 33333
```

Each time it changes .. and the comparison comes with an error "This is a false key"

this is my 5 text box

```
Box1.Text
Box2.Text
Box3.Text
Box4.Text
Box5.Text
```

and this my stringbuilder code

```cs
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
    if (c is TextBox)
    {
        sb.Append(c.Text);
    }
}
Activation.activateSoftware(sb.ToString());
```

What am I missing here..

**¤ Solved ¤**

Thanks all for your responses.. But the topic has been closed ?? I do not know why.. But the important problem was solved.. And I wanted to share the solution.

The problem I had was in tab order on Windows Forms so I modified the order of Text box In **Visual Studio**, on the **View menu**, **Tab Order**.

And the problem has been resolved .. **Thanks again to all**

Comment: Are you saying the order of the Controls inside that foreach loop is different on each run? That is highly unusual if that is the case. Are you maybe just missing the spaces between the 5 number goups?

Comment: So I wouldn't rely on the lists in `this.Controls` always coming in identical order; for example, with dynamic forms. Since there are "only" five text boxes, I would connect them without a loop, as suggested by T.S., and to be on the safe side, I would use Trim() to make sure that no unwanted characters have slipped in.

Comment: It looks like you might be trying to provide the user five individual `TextBox` controls for input data that will be combined to validate a key value--like an "user access key". If that is what you want and you are using WinForms then you might have a look at `MaskedTextBox`. Here are the [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox?view=net-5.0)

Answer (score 1):

Just do this for putting it together

```
string x = Box1.Text + Box2.Text + Box3.Text + Box4.Text + Box5.Text;
```

And this for showing

```
Box1.Text = x.Substring(0, 5);
Box2.Text = x.Substring(5, 5);
Box3.Text = x.Substring(10, 5);
Box4.Text = x.Substring(15, 5);
Box5.Text = x.Substring(20);
```

Another option would be

```cs
//put together
string x = string.Join('.', new string[]{Box1.Text, Box2.Text, Box3.Text, Box4.Text, Box5.Text});

// display
string[] items = x.Split(".".ToCharArray());
Box1.Text = items[0];
Box2.Text = items[1];
Box3.Text = items[2];
Box4.Text = items[3];
Box5.Text = items[4];
```